# DB connections works with Kubernetes cluster but fails with Skaffold dev

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, skaffold

I have a k8 cluster setup where Im using kustomize to build my deployment.yaml then actually deploying with kubectl. I have a FE, BE and a local DB with persistant volume. Works just fine however when I add skaffold for local dev, the container logs indicate DB connection fails. Been at it for a few days and I can't figure out whats wrong
[image: Link of Skaffold Logs (I cant post yet)]

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient information to help diagnose. It sounds like there's a configuration issue in your `skaffold.yaml`.  `skaffold render` will show you the manifests that will be deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Turns out this was an issue with my container not reading flyway configs properly. Still unsure why this happens only with skaffold but I found a workaround